# Simple iterative method to solve $X-\alpha X^{-1} = A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms

The is a simple iteration to compute $A^{-1}$ by applying Newton's method to
$$X^{-1} = A,$$
namely the iteration
$$X_{n+1} = X_n(2I - AX_n).$$

Is there is similarly simple iteration to solve the equation
$$X - \alpha X^{-1} = A$$
for $\alpha>0$?

I am only interested in the case where $A$ is symmetric positive definite and I also look for positive semidefinite answers $X$…

Comment: Did you try Newton's method for this case? $x-a-cx^{-1}$ is concave and strictly growing for $x>0$, which is optimal for global convergence of Newton's method. This should transfer to the matrix case, starting with $X_0=A$ to remain in the commutative algebra generated by $A$.

Comment: I tried but could not see how to do the Newton step, i.e. I could not solve the respective equation for the update

Comment: The step $S$ is the solution of $-(S+αX^{-1}SX^{-1})=X-αX^{-1}-A$. If $S$ and $X$ are in the algebra of $A$, then they commute and one gets $S=-(X^2+αI)^{-1}X(X^2-αI-AX)$. The Newton step expression can be further simplified.

Comment: May help to first diagonalize $A$, then iterations is $O(n)$ instead of $O(n^2)$, $n$ being the size of A, and will be just $n$ scalar cases.

Comment: Actually $O(n^{2.x})$ for inversion. We have a closed form solution in the scalar case. As pointed out by @Lutz Lemann, everything commutes so we can also use $(A + (A^2+4\alpha I)^{1/2})/2$, using the sqrtm function.

Comment: I doubt Newton's method will maintain semidefiniteness in $X$ without additional parameterization

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! Th observation that X and A commute is quite helpful. My first implementation shows some weird behavior - the initialization makes a big difference and often I see very small error after a few iteration and the dramatic increase again…

Comment: @whpowell96 : Disregarding floating-point errors, if starting with $A$ or $I$, then every iterate will be a polynomial in $A$, thus commute. One could also say that the iteration if seen in the eigenbasis of $A$, is the scalar iteration on the eigenvalues, and due to the form of the function the iterates of the eigenvalue will lie between 0 and the eigenvalue, monotonically increasing (after the first step).

Comment: @LutzLehmann I somehow can't make this works - maybe a stability issue. The approach using the square root works quite ok!

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see. I guess the only issue is the quality of the initial guess, which is typically. I'm curious how the condition of $A$ factors in here. This is similar to some Krylov methods for rational functions so it may be possible to use some techniques from those methods to stabilize or globalize the iteration better.

Comment: In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08366.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05854.pdf) the problem with Newton method for square root may be with errors in the intermediate steps making the matrices no longer commute, and it could be the case for this equation. Sra mentioned the Polar Newton method in Higham's book seems to address that issue and I presume is implemented in standard library matrix square root functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the coefficient $\alpha$ is redundant: w.l.o.g $\alpha=1$ since we can normalize it with the change of variables $\tilde{X}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}X$ and $\tilde{A}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}A$. From the discussion, the solution should not contain an inverse.

The equation
$$ X+X^{-1}=A$$
is just a quadratic matrix equation
$$ X^2-AX+I=0$$

An explicit solution is given by the formula for the scalar quadratic equation (which we can use in a matrix sense directly since all matrices commute) as essentially also pointed out in Jonas solution:

$$ X=\frac{1}{2}(A\pm \sqrt{A^2-4I})$$

To avoid inverses, we can use "two-variable method" for the square root, which needs to be scaled to be inside the applicable interval https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#A_two-variable_iterative_method

Initiate:
$$ S=\frac{1}{\|A^2-4I\|}(A^2-4I)$$
$$ A_0=S$$
$$ C_0=S-I$$
Iterate:
$$ A_{k+1}\leftarrow A_k-A_kC_k/2$$
$$ C_{k+1}\leftarrow C_k^2(C_k-3I)/4$$
until convergence.

Solution given by

$$ X=\frac{1}{2}(A+\sqrt{\|A^2-4I\|}A_k)$$

The norm can be chosen essentially arbitrary, but should be cheap to compute, so e.g. the Frobenius norm.

Applicability: This will only work if $A^2-4I$ positive definite, but if that's not satisfied the solution is complex so probably not what is of interest in this application. Roundoff errors can probably be substantial, since e.g. symmetry is not preserved. A standard quick fix trick which might help is to make $A_k$ symmetric in every step $A_k \leftarrow \frac{1}{2}(A_k+A_k^T)$.

Comment: Thanks, Elias! I did something quite similar, but missed the right initialization. Will try out as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be an elegant solution using matrix function ideas.

First of all, we can write $A  = V \Lambda V^T = X - \alpha X^{-1}$, with $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ being the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$. By the form we are given for $A$ and $X$, it is easy to see that they are simultaneously diagonalisable. Therefore, the relationship of $A$ and $X$ can be translated into a relationship of their eigenvalues $\lambda_i = \mu_i - \alpha/\mu_i$, where $\mu_i$ is the eigenvalue of $X$ corresponding to the eigenvector $V_i$. If we invert this relationship, we get

$$\mu = (\lambda - \sqrt{4 \alpha + \lambda^2})/2 \text{  or  } \mu = (\lambda + \sqrt{4 a + \lambda^2})/2.$$
Only the second solution will yield positive eigenvalues.
Thus, if we define $f(\lambda) = (\lambda + \sqrt{4 \alpha + \lambda^2})/2$, then $X = f(A)$. To evaluate $f(A)$, we need to take care of the principal matrix square root of $4\alpha I + A^2$. We could employ an iterative method [1] for that square root. Alternatively, we could probably build an iterative method through an appropriate iterative approximation of $f$. (Padé?)

[1] Higham, N.J. Stable iterations for the matrix square root. Numerical Algorithms 15, 227–242 (1997). https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1019150005407

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: What worked well: Use Denman-Beavers for the square root. However, this needs two matrix inversions for iteration. The Schulz iteration from Higham's paper needs that the matrix is close to the identity, iisc…

Comment: It will feel less satisfying than an actual iterative method, but approximating the function $f$ (that is very close to linear for $\lambda$ sufficiently large) by a Padé approximation (or even Taylor), might give you a very good result. (Take a look: https://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/2067/1/paper.pdf)

Comment: Are you looking for $X$ or $Xb$ for some vector $b$?

Comment: I want the inverse explicitly (it is a part of a numerical example for a different method: The X is actually the proximal map of the function $X\mapsto -\log(\det(X))$ and we have some method which can work with approximate proximal maps and look for nice examples.

Comment: Oh, and an update: If one computes the inverses in Denman-Beavers also with Newton, the method is explicit, stable and quite fast.